# Pass more than 100 arguments in Stored Proc - PostgreSQL9.5

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.5

I have a Stored Proc with more than 100 arguments but due to the default value of max_function_args set to 100, I am not able to create this STP. Can someone tell me how to change the value of `FUNC_MAX_ARGS` so that I can have this STP created with more than 100 args.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a horrible design. But you can probably get away with it, by creating a custom type with 100 fields, then pass a single argument of that type

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thank you

Comment: If they are all a single datatype, why not an array?

Answer (score 1):

Odds are *really* good that this is the wrong thing to do, but it's a #define in [pg_config_manual.h](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/pg__config__manual_8h_source.html) Having said that, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

```
   25 /*
   26  * Maximum number of arguments to a function.
   27  *
   28  * The minimum value is 8 (GIN indexes use 8-argument support functions).
   29  * The maximum possible value is around 600 (limited by index tuple size in
   30  * pg_proc's index; BLCKSZ larger than 8K would allow more).  Values larger
   31  * than needed will waste memory and processing time, but do not directly
   32  * cost disk space.
   33  *
   34  * Changing this does not require an initdb, but it does require a full
   35  * backend recompile (including any user-defined C functions).
   36  */
   37 #define FUNC_MAX_ARGS       100
```